# numerical base conversion on Intel 8086

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16

I'm working on a numerical base conversion program and I've stumbled upon a problem in one part of the code:

```
    mov ax,36864
    mov bx,ax
    mov dx,0
    sub bx,4096
    jns ustawGr
    mov al,48
    int 29h
    jmp konwerter16
```

It works fine for numbers up to 36863, but for some reason it is not going into `ustawGr` and prints `0` for any higher number even though the register should be able to contain it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`36864 - 4096` is `0x9000 - 0x1000 == 0x8000`. In [two's complement representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) `0x8000` is the greatest negative 16-bit number (`-32768`). And since the value is negative, your `jns` won't be taken.